# com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi

I have the following RMI Connection code which returns a com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to Client.AdditionInterface error. I created two separate packages Client & Server and putted the Interface in both of them. Here is my complete code:

```
package Serveur;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry; 

public class AdditionServer {

public static void main (String[] argv) {
    try {
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);     
        Addition Hello = new Addition();     
        Naming.rebind("rmi://"+java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()+"/ABC", Hello);     
        System.out.println("Addition Server is ready.");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Addition Server failed: " + e);
    }
}
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////

```
package Serveur;
 import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;


public class Addition extends UnicastRemoteObject implements AdditionInterface {

public Addition () throws RemoteException {
    super(); 
}

@Override
public int add(int a, int b) throws RemoteException {
    int result=a+b;
    return result;
}

@Override
public String aff(int a, int b) throws RemoteException {
    return String.valueOf(add(a, b));

}
}
```

////////////////////////////

```
package Client;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

 public interface AdditionInterface extends Remote {
     public int add(int a,int b) throws RemoteException;
     public String aff(int a, int b) throws RemoteException;
 }
```

////////////////////////////

```
package Client;
import java.rmi.*;


public class AdditionClient {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {      
        AdditionInterface add = (AdditionInterface) Naming.lookup("rmi://"+java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()+"/ABC");
        System.out.println("Result is :"+add.add(9, 10));
        System.out.println(add.aff(26, 45));
    }
}
```

Any help please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in both a `Client.AdditionInterface` for the client and a `Server.AdditionInterface` for the server?  Effectively the error is saying `Server.AdditionInterface cannot be cast to Client.AdditionInterface`.

With RMI you must have the same interface class on both client and server, but then clearly the server implementation class (`AdditionServer`) just on the server.  The interface could be in a shared package (e.g. `common.AdditionInterface` ).